# Javascript - Strange behavior with indexing object arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a conundrum involving the following code:

```
$scope.getUserContact = function(data) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: [Removed]
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            alert(data.length);
            alert(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
            ...
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
        });
    }
}
```

First line spits out:

```
[ 
    {
        "listingId":"String",
        ...other Strings and ints ...
    }
]
```

Basically, it spits out an array consisting of one object.

Second line spits out

`1`

As expected, the length of the array is 1.

Third line spits out

`undefined`

I just don't understand how indexing an array suddenly results in `undefined` instead of giving me the object at the index.

It may be notable that `data` is a parameter to a function.

Any help? I assume it's either a stupid error on my part or some strange and unknown behavior from the depths of JavaScript.

Comment: We need to see what `data` is.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Updated, though I only listed one field. The rest are all Strings and Numbers.

Comment: see `i` value after `alert(data.length);`

Comment: @Mahi Thank you very much. i is 1 instead of 0. Would the cause be the callback running with the new value of i? If so, what would be the most effective way to ensure that the index used in the callback is the correct index?

Comment: @AndrewFan i don't know why that happened .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `$http` request is asynchronous so

- first the loop will initialize all requests
- then when i = data.length the requests will end and every callbacks will be called with the last value of i, not the one you wanted

You should do something like that to not use the same `i` in the callback

```js
$scope.getUserContact = function(data) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    doRequest(data, i);
  }
}

function doRequest(data, i) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: [Removed]
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    alert(data.length);
    alert(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
    ...
  }, function errorCallback(response) {});
}
```

Also if you want more control with your flow you should use the promises from [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```js
$scope.getUserContact = function(data) {
  var requests = data.map(function(d, i) {
    return doRequest(data, i)
  });
  return $q.all(requests).then(function(requestsResults) {
    // do something when every requests have ended
  });
}

function doRequest(data, i) {
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: [Removed]
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // do something when this request have ended
  }, function errorCallback(response) {});
}
```

Comment: I need to set data after receiving the results of all of the requests, so how would I have another callback run upon completion of all the calls to doRequest?

Comment: Actually, it's fine - I can update the data after every iteration. Thank you.

Comment: To wait for a call you can return the promise that $http is using (just a simple return), to wait for every calls you can use `$q.all`

Comment: I just edited to add links and an example of using the $http promise for that